# Angularjs html not taking bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am trying to learn AngularJS .i am not getting any bootstrap themes on my web application:

Below is the html code for the header that i am trying :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav   navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class ="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fetching data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

i have also imported Bootstrap in my project :

```
"test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

please let me know if you require any more files of angularjs !

Thankyou.

below is the image of my application in which Header has not bootstrap thyeme [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75hwr.png)

Comment: Hmm, did you add bootstrap to your packages? like `npm install bootstrap`?

Answer (score 0):

First, open the browser developer tool and check if Bootstrap css file is loaded. If it's loaded your theme should be applied correctly, so I suspect something is wrong with the file path and css file cannot be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap doesn't work well with angular.js as it dependes on jQuery. Try using [ui-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead